# seaborn.boxenplot - How to display the mean values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, mean, median

`showmeans = True` in boxplot diplays the means.

Is there a way to display mean values for seaborn.boxenplot in addition to the median line?

What would be a low cost but detailed (similar to boxenplot) solution?

P.S. Google search motors can not distinguish the difference between boxenplot and boxplot.

---

**EDIT: THE RESULT FOLLOWING YOZHIKOFF'S SOLUTION:**
[image]
**code:**

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,5))
a1 = sns.boxenplot(y = 'price', x = 'grade', data=df2 )
a1 = sns.scatterplot(data=df2.groupby('grade')['price'].mean(), zorder=10)
a1.set(yscale='log')
plt.xticks(rotation=60);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to approach it would be to simply draw means separately, so altering the `seaborn.boxenplot` example from the docs a bit we have this

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
proxy_df = tips.groupby('day')["total_bill"].mean().to_frame().reset_index()

ax = sns.stripplot(x="day",  y="total_bill", data=proxy_df, zorder=10,  color='C0', linewidth=1, jitter=False, edgecolor='lightgray')
ax = sns.boxenplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
```

Note that we use `zorder` here to force means to be drawn on top of `boxenplots`.

Comment: Oh right, very cool approach actually. The thing is two plots does not coincide correctly for my data. It is either scatter plot covers a smaller x-span or is skewed to the right.

Comment: I don't see any reasons why that could happen. One even more general approach would be to plot the scatterplot using `matplotlib`, having full control of the marker positions. Could you make a minimal example of how your data looks like so I can reproduce the misalignment?

Comment: I have provided the screenshot.

Comment: I've updated the snippet to a more general version, it should work for your case now.

Comment: Ok, cool hack. It worked without `to_frame()`, too. The only minor problem is that dots are slightly off the center horizontally. In most cases this would not be a serious issue. Thank you.

Comment: For me the dots are aligned just perfectly... Are you using the `jitter=False` option?

Comment: Oh, I missed that part. Thank you.